# Custom Types in/with DLLImport'ed / P/Invoke'd win32 dll?

Tags: .net, winapi, pinvoke, types, dllimport

Good afternoon,

i am currently wrestling with an old .dll which functionality I have to re-use in a .Net application & I came so far to import the basic/easy functions/methods that return bool etc, but some do in fact also expect (or return) an type that is declared within the .dll.

How would I handle this? How would I map/create that type in my .net environment?? Is that possible at all?

Cheers and thanks,
-Jörg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "type", I assume you mean struct, otherwise you'll have to find out how to map a struct in memory to your type.

You'll have to create the same struct in your .NET application, and mark it with the `StructLayout` attribute (`LayoutKind.Sequential` is the most common). Then you should be able to pass a reference to the struct.

The [Platform Invoke Tutorial on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468.aspx#pinvoke_custommarshaling) is also quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you would typically create a struct in the .NET code that mirrors the expected data layout, using some of the `[StructLayout]` options (sequential or explicit) - and pass that struct over the PInvoke boundary (i.e. on the imported API).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want, but I will give it a shoot!

I use a delphi dll in one of my applications (ASP.NET) and I had to create a wrapper, I know that for winforms there is no need to create the wrapper DLL but you need to map the methods, I'm pasting 2 methods from that DLL and how do I call them:

```
    #region DllImport

    [DllImport("LicenseInterface.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
               CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "EncodeString")]
    private static extern int _EncodeString(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string secret,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string str,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder encodedStr,
        int encodedBufferSize);

    [DllImport("LicenseInterface.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
               CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "DecodeString")]
    private static extern int _DecodeString(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string secret,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string str,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder decodedStr,
        int decodedBufferSize);

    #endregion


    public static int EncodeString(string str, ref string encodedStr)
    {
        StringBuilder _encodedString = new StringBuilder(2000);
        int ret = _EncodeString("aYs6aL9b8722XXe43", str, _encodedString, _encodedString.Capacity);
        encodedStr = _encodedString.ToString();
        return ret;
    }

    public static int DecodeString(string str, ref string decodedStr)
    {
        StringBuilder _decodedString = new StringBuilder(2000);
        int ret = _DecodeString("aYs6aL9b8722XXe43", str, _decodedString, _decodedString.Capacity);
        decodedStr = _decodedString.ToString();
        return ret;
    }

public License()
{
   // code...
   License.DecodeKey(moduleKey, ref serial, ref moduleId, ref expirationDate, ref userData);
   // more code...
}
```